# mysql, getting time period between two time's when date and time are in separated column

Tags: mysql

I need to query the info in MySql where I'm given two time strings, so I need to find anything in between.

the format the table looks like

```
id | date      | hour | other | columns | that are not important
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2016-04-11| 1    | asdsa......
2  | 2016-04-11| 2    | asdasdsadsadas...
.
.
.
n  | 2016-04-12| 23   | sadasdsadsadasd
```

Say I have the time strings `2016-04-11 1` and `2016-04-12 23` and I need to find all info from 1 to n. I can separate the date and hour and do a query using `BETWEEN...AND` for the date, but I have no idea how to fit the time into the formula. Using another `BETWEEN` definitely won't work, so I definitely need to fit the statement somewhere else. I'm not sure how to proceed though.

Comment: I can use two `SELECT` clauses in the `WHERE` part to get the query right, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE ((`date` = fromDate AND `hour` > fromHour) OR `date` > fromDate)
AND ((`date` = toDate AND `hour` < toHour) OR `date` < toDate)
```

Comment: thanks! my method has the same performance but this is definitely cleaner.